# tableau is it possible instead of have each addr on the left side to be a buckets of counts of duplicated records in each client and month

Tags: database, tableau-api

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZWKz.png)

what I am trying to is , let's say I have two address in that share the same office and month then put 2 instead of having both addresses

Comment: Hello, I cannot seem to spot the difference between images. Can you try to provide more detailed explanation what do you desire to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry , I posted them twice bot pictures are the same, What I am trying to do is instead of having each address in rows, I wan instead to have counts for these addresses, like 2387 records that are in client code amfn and exmt in october